# How to set padding Bootstrap when left element has float propery?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 block">
<div class="col-md-4 photo">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1282701351808739/"><img src=""></a></div>
<div class="col-md-8"><h4><span style="font-weight: bold;">Gracie Huff</span></h4><p class="review-comment" style="line-height: 1.6;"><span>Oh my goodness! Your work is so precious and beautiful!!! I love what you do and I hope you continue to keep up the fabulous work!!! ❤❤</span></p>
```

Problem is that block `col-md-4` has property `float:left`.
If text in block `.col-md-8` is so long it comes to under block `col-md-4 photo`.

Sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/053mq1vu/)

So, how to fix this?

As solution I can set fixed height for element: `div.photo`

Comment: perhaps not getting it right but do you need <div class="col-md-4 photo" style="float:left;">? either assign another class having float:left and use it for or assign it in .photo class.

Comment: According to Bootstrap documentation, your columns should be inside a `<div class="row">`, which should be inside a div class `container` or `container-fluid`

Comment: I can not use `row` cause I need to show dinamicly columns on the fulll page as possible

Comment: Updated verison https://jsfiddle.net/053mq1vu/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bootstrap col's you have space for a total of 12 inside a row.

Please take a look at the grid documentation. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

So in your example 3 + 4 + 8 = 15 . So that's 3 too many. In my code example below i divided the page into 3 even columns. So you do 12/3 = 4 so you give each class col-md-4 . If you don't want even columns you can play with the numbers at the end. But never go above 12 or they will not fit into a single row.

Also the basic structure involves a container and a row.
If you want the container to be full-width you can add container-fluid instead of container to your top-level div.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/739844199505120/"><img src="https://fb-s-b-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/14724409_686756244813916_4119560930105375585_n.jpg?oh=0d295e97d3818a2ba788015d38385376&amp;oe=590D81DC&amp;__gda__=1494163569_54508491e4fd3d1197960c466dfee235"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4 class="strong"><strong>Anastasia Michelle Archuleta</strong></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="review-comment" style="line-height: 1.6;">
       <span>I can't stop looking at these cute creatures!  I'm so in love with all of them! I'm saving up for one, what one is going to be a very hard decision that's for sure!</span>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need four columns, your example does containers by row

Comment: if you need four columns you have to add another col , inside that row and count the totals to 12. Please take a look at the bootstrap documentation about grids

Comment: Please update your original question, because your fiddle and the question are two different html codes. I edited my post to show you how to get them next to each other